# how can I get current value to qcombobox in pyqt?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qcombobox

I need to get the selected value in my qcombobox. It was populated from database, the QCombobox is named cbUser This is my function that populate the qcombobox:

```
for row in self.SELECT_USERS_ACCOUNTS():
    self.cbUser.addItem(str(row[1]),int(row[0]))
```

The data is showed successfully in the qcombobox cbUser.
and I get a function to will get the value to the selected item:

```
def getValue(self):
    id_us = self.cbUser.itemData(self.cbUser.currentIndex())
    print(str(id_us))
```

The print shows  and it's not the data, the correct data is an integer value for example 1 or 2 ....
Please help me, thanks in advance.

UPDATED:
The solution was to modify the first line code into getValue function (add .toPyObject()):

```
id_us = self.cbUser.itemData(self.cbUser.currentIndex()).toPyObject()
```

Comment: I addded toPyObject and I got It. id_us = self.cbUser.itemData(self.cbUser.currentIndex()).toPyObject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to modify the first line code into getValue function (add .toPyObject()):

```
id_us = self.cbUser.itemData(self.cbUser.currentIndex()).toPyObject()
```

With this I saw the value stored in the qcombobox.